# Application Error on Heroku Node App

Tags: node.js, rest, express, heroku

I've recently deployed a node REST API to Heroku on the free tier. When I deploy, it works perfectly for 30-60 seconds. Then, it responds with an Application error. Below is the code in the server.js file.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mysql = require('mysql')
var path = require('path');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express()
app.use(cors());
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
//middleware that allows reactjs app to access api from a different port
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
}

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


//parse requests of Content-Type
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
//parse requests of content-type application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

require("./app/routes/MainRoutes")(app)

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.listen(port,"0.0.0.0",()=>{
    console.log("Server is running on port " + port )
})
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("hello")
    res.status(200).send({message:"Curricula API" })
})
```

Comment: Could you add the error your application crashes with? See [Heroku logging](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#types-of-logs) (`heroku logs`)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the cause of the heroku application error by typing `heroku logs` check this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging